# How to get rid of spacing in SimpleDocTemplate(). Python. ReportLab

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation

Do someone know if it possible to delete default spancing when i'm making PDF document with  SimpleDocTemplate().

I want it to print from corner to corner.

```
   response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'

    # Our container for 'Flowable' objects
    elements = []

    # A large collection of style sheets pre-made for us
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

    # A basic document for us to write to 'rl_hello_table.pdf'
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response)

    #    elements.append(Paragraph("Wumpus vs Cave Population Report",
#    styles['Title']))

    data = [
           ['Deep Ditch',    50],
           ['Death Gully',   5000],
           ['Dire Straits', 600],
           ['Deadly Pit',    5],
           ['Deep Ditch',    50],
           ['Deep Ditch',    50],
           ['Death Gully',   5000],
           ['Dire Straits', 600],
           ['Deadly Pit',    5],
           ['Deep Ditch',    50],
                                  ]

    # Create the table with the necessary style, and add it to the
    # elements list.
    table = Table(data, colWidths=270, rowHeights=70)
    elements.append(table)

    # Write the document to response
    doc.build(elements) 

    return response
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, rightMargin=0, leftMargin=0, topMargin=0, bottomMargin=0)
```